# Rearranging GOTO's using ASM [JAVA]

Tags: java, obfuscation, bytecode

I am looking at an obfuscated application, and the application seems to have a lot of GOTO's which I want to rearrange or remove

The question is, how would I go about doing this?

```
for(final MethodNode mn : classNode.methods) {
            final BIF is = new BIF(mn); //BIF is my bytecode instruction finder
            AbstractInsnNode ain;
            while ((ain = is.next()) != null) {
                if (ain instanceof JumpInsnNode && ain.getOpcode() == GOTO) {
                    final JumpInsnNode jump = (JumpInsnNode) ain;
                    mn.instructions.remove(jump);
                    removed++;
                }
            }
        }
```

So I've tried just removing them all, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know how to rearrange them

Comment: Post some code. Tell us what you've tried. Tell us what issues you've run into.

Comment: eww goto... run away run away!

Comment: It would be rather weird if you could just remove all the GOTOs and it would still work, no? It's not dead code obviously.

Comment: You can kind of have `goto` with `break` and a ton of strategically placed curly braces.

Comment: Have you tried the Krakatau decompiler (https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)? It's pretty good at dealing with control flow obfuscation like this. If that doesn't work, send me the obfuscated classes (assuming you can legally) and I'll see if I can figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to solve this easily, it looks like a quite radical obfuscation mechanism. You could try to un-goto it, linearizing the code by defragmenting the chunks between goto jumps. But then, some goto's are legitimate flow control jumps, so you'll need a way to detect this. It looks like a real challenge, one that will take much of your time. But, maybe the challenge is intruguing enough to push forward :)

Comment: Thank you! Yes it is radically obfuscated. The obfuscation also throws in dummy methods and fake try catch blocks which I've managed to solve, but goto's have been the biggest problem :P

Comment: Or you could use Krakatau, which does this automatically. (Disclosure, I wrote it)

Comment: @Antimony I guessed that by your engaged comment above :) But is the output of Krakatau something wherefrom you can easily read out program logic, as opposed to something which is just a behavioral equivalent of the bytecode in Java? Because that would be the main point of de-obfuscation.

Comment: @Marko That depends on how badly it's been obfuscated. Krakatau does some deobfuscation automatically, but for best results manual deobfuscation is also required. But then again, that would be true no matter what you're using. Anyway, one of my goals is to make it easier for people to add custom passes, but I'm still experimenting with that.